# Why is $\textbf{A} = A_i \textbf{e}_i$ not independent of choice of coordinates?

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm currently reading "Tensors, Differential forms and Variational Principles" By D. Lovelock and H. Rund. This is from page 2 :

[image]

and then on page 7, concerning equation 1.1

[image]

I fail to understand why equation 1.1 should depend on a coordinate system.
I seems to me that the $\mathbf{e}_i$, as defined in the first paragraph, are legit vectors independently of them being used as a basis for the space.

Are the authors implying that the symbols $\mathbf{e}_i$ are just placeholders, whose actual vectors they are referring to would change depending on the choice of coordinate system ?

Comment: The author is trying to tell you that the equality is dependent on the choice of $e_{i}$. For example consider the vector $(1,0,0)$. In usual sense, you would think that it just means the point on the $x$ axis. But this is dependent on the fact that you are refering to the rectangular axis as your coordinates.

Comment: So, if I consider another basis, say of vectors $(0,1,1), (1,0,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$. Then this point becomes $[-1/2,1/2,1/2]$ wrt to those coordinates. That is, $(1,0,0)=-1/2(0,1,1)+1/2(1,0,1)+1/2(1,1,0)$. So it would not be very helpful to write $(1,0,0)=[-1/2,1/2,1/2]$ as the representations depend on the choice of your coordinate system. Instead, when someone writes $A=B$ when $A=A_{1}e_{1}+A_{2}e_{2}+A_{3}e_{3}$, then if $B=B_{1}e_{1}+B_{2}e_{2}+B_{3}e_{3}$, and $A=B$, then we must have that $A_{i}=B_{i}$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: But suppose, someone asks you to tell the position of the sun as you see it. Then depending on how you view it, youll say it is in A position. Now another person on another side of the world or oriented otherwise, will say that it is in B positon. But the sun itself is a fixed point in our space. Then again, would it make sense to say $A=B$ unless you and the other guy is at the same place on earth and oriented in the same way despite the fact that both of you are refering to the same fixed object, the sun in our space?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron So what you are basically saying is that the answer to the question I worded at the end of my post is "yes" ?

Comment: Well, the vector, or the point in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$ as an element of the set $\Bbb{R}^{3}$ to which it is refering to, is independent of the choice of coordinates and is just a set element (and we all know that sets don't come with a inherent coordinate structure). But, the way you view the point depends on where you are positioned in the $3D$ space. So the equality won't make sense, unsless you are fixing a basis.

Comment: That is to indirectly say that these $e_{i}$ are placeholders and the equality does not make sense unless you apriori have a meaning as to what equality among elements represented by different placeholder symbols actually mean. That is why I used the sun example. You see that it apriori assumes the sun is a fixed immovable object in our space and then defined the notion of positions which is dependent on our point of view. And well say that that our and someone's other's positioning make sense if we are both refering to the same immovable object.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Ok, what got me confused it that, in the text, they start by choosing three directions in the space, and then associate with them the $e_i$. According to me, at this point the $e_i$ are well defined vectors that owe nothing to any choice of basis. To use your example, if I defined the vector $A$ to be along my nose, and that the vector from me to the sun is $aA$, you would also agree on that. But if we say that $A$ represents the first vector in any basis triplet, then of course the actual choice of basis will matter. Am I correct ?

Comment: "Start by choosing three directions in space". Well, that's a choice by definition really. And they will form a "basis", if these three directions are linearly independent. So yes, the actual choice of basis is your choice of the coordinate system you want to use. The coordinate axes are formed as a result of your choice of basis. They need not be perpendicular to each other though. If they are, they are called orthogonal coordinates. For example, I can take $(1,0,0) , (0,1,0)$ and $(0,37,24)$ as my basis. In this case, the axis of the 2nd vector and the third are not perpendicular.

Comment: Ofcourse, if you drop geometric intuition, then there's a purely algebraic and abstract construction for $\Bbb{R}^{3}$. In that case, you just need $3$ placeholders. You can call them anything like "happy", "sad" and "grumpy" . They basically act as abstract symbols. You then let $\Bbb{R}^{3}=\{c_{1}\text{happy} +c_{2}\text{sad}+c_{3}\text{grumpy}:c_{1},c_{2},c_{3}\in\Bbb{R}\}$ and you define addition between any two of the elements in the natural way (i.e. coordinate wise i.e. symbol wise). This is what is called formal linear combinations and is an abstract way of presenting the same thing.